# Prolog - How to use the facts in an array of facts?

Tags: arrays, prolog, label

Beginner to prolog here; just wanted to ask a question to get rid of some of the confusion I am having with an assignment question.

Suppose I had a list of facts (in this case, a list of people and foods they eat and # of items),

```
label(test,
  [eats(george,apple,3),
   eats(bob,orange,1),
   eats(joe,steak,1)]).
```

how do I use the facts inside this array? For example, how would I get this to work?

```
eaten(Person,Food):-
  eats(Person,Food,_).
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question make little sense because of lack of context.

A possible usage for a list of facts it's to push it in DB:

```
?- maplist(assert, [eats(george,apple,3), eats(bob,orange,1), eats(joe,steak,1)]).
true.

?- eats(Person,Food,_).
Person = george,
Food = apple ;
Person = bob,
Food = orange ;
Person = joe,
Food = steak.
```

but again, it's all about your remaining rules...

*edit* Usually the 'information flow' is reversed: we start from DB facts, collects relevant data to a list and process the list. Daniel explained about accessing elements of the list. Consider that after the assertion of facts from the list, your rules will have access to facts. With the rule you listed, after:

```
?- retractall(eats(_,_,_)),
   maplist(assert, [eats(george,apple,3), eats(bob,orange,1), eats(joe,steak,1)]).

?- eaten(bob,X).
X = orange.
```

HTH

Comment: a better question might be: If I had a list of facts, how do I access these facts? My code is literally those 6 lines in my initial question but I have no idea how to access the  `eats(george,apple,3) ` in my rules/queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're asking. The answer is to use `member/2` like this:

```
eaten(Person, Food) :- 
  label(test, Eating),
  member(eats(Person, Food, _), Eating).
```

Is this the result you want?

```
?- eaten(P, F).
P = george,
F = apple ;
P = bob,
F = orange ;
P = joe,
F = steak.
```

As a rule of thumb, it would probably be more "standard" to pass the list along than to store it in a big clump like that. And I would probably say that this is a list of `eats/3` *structures* rather than *facts*, but this usage kind of blurs the distinction, since what's in the database is a an arity 2 fact called `label` rather than a group of arity 3 facts called `eats`. But they are actually in the database, in a roundabout way. Interesting.

This approach, using `member` to poke through a list, is also commonly used to supply options to a procedure. `open/4` uses it, for instance.